# nodeJS and AngularjS -app.get method was never been called

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I really dont know what I am doing wrong ...but my app.get function doesn t work ..when I try to look at networking in Chrome ..there was a HTTP status 302 Found ..but its never go into that function on server side ..I really dont know what I am doing wrong ..help please. .or ask more information I dont know what should be the important ..
Here is my server.js function :

```
app.get('/api/tests/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('get tests id')
    console.log(req.params.id)
    Test.findById(req.params.id, function(err, test) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        console.log(test)
        res.send(test);
    });
});
```

here is app.js Angular rouiting ..

```
.when('/tests/:id',{
                templateUrl: 'templates/testView.html',
                controller: 'TestViewCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
```

here is my HTML menu.html file ..where I want to go on that specific address:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in tests">
                <div>

                    <a href="/tests/{{test._id}}">{{test.testName}}</a>
                </div>
                </div>
```

..in controller menu.html I´ve got post method because GET method too doesnt work ..

```
$scope.getTests = function () {

            $http.post('/api/getTestText')
                .success(function (data) {
                   $scope.tests = data;
```

and in detail page for each test is my HTML till now blank ..but in Controller I have something like this :

```
 .controller('TestViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams','Test', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, Test) {

        Test.get({_id: $routeParams.id},function(test){
            $scope.test=test;
            console.log($scope.test)
```

and test factory.js :

```
.factory('Test', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/tests/:id');
    }]);
```

I dont think so that the problem is in front-End side ..but maybe is ..
I heard something about postman app from google chrome apps ...but when I type there my HTTP call ..

localhost:3000/api/tests/ and as params I set _id and IDvalue as value ..the result is same like when I do it by click on menu Item ..

```
localhost:3000/api/tests?id=5726aa164a26bbe4180700ea
```

But  console.log no working in the server.js side ..so it never goes into app.get() I think...

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the `_id` field from the body into `:id` in the url param.

To achieve this, change this:

```
.factory('Test', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/tests/:id');
}]);
```

Into:

```
.factory('Test', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    //This plugs in the _id field from the body and injects it into the url param.
    //This is an example with mongodb default _id field assuming that's what you use.
    return $resource('/api/tests/:id', {id: '@_id'}); 
}]);
```

Comment: maybe its good answer ..but I found the problem ...It was in the server.js file ...I really don t know how but I have app.get("*") at the begining of server.js file ...and that was the problem ...so that is the main reason why I couldn t call get methods ..and after that Is everything work ...so thanks but the problem was elsewhere